# Measuring current usage in a wheelchair power assist device

Tags: power, battery-charging, dc-motor, recording

I am working on wheelchair configuration methods to reduce upper extremity overuse syndrome in daily users.  I want to compare two tire types over a course that consists of obstacles that place strain on the upper extremities.  A power assist device called SmartDrive pushes the chair along by a single wheel and a lithium ion powered motor trailing behind the wheelchair.  Is it valid, or even feasible to use a recording ammeter plugged into the charger port on the SmartDrive to measure amp hours used over a specific course and compare between wheelchair A and wheelchair B?  If so, is there a simple and inexpensive way of measuring amp-hours consumed over a course?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot open the device and put a [cheap watt meter](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07PB13BF3/) on the battery leads?

Comment: I think that could be done.  It sounds like it might be the most straight forward way of getting to what I want to measure.  Thanks!

Comment: Will the cheap watt meter display a cumulative value of watts used?

Comment: Yes, it will. [This listing](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B08CSCRGG1/) has better description of the functions. I can't vouch for its precision, but should be good enough for comparative purposes, as in your question

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.  Without a wiring diagram, which I hope to obtain, I am unsure about whether or not it would work to wire the watt meter into the +/- leads of the charger port.  Based on my limited knowledge of electronics, I am surmising that with the battery between the charger port and the motor itself, it will affect any measurement of watts consumed by the motor.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The watt meter should go between the battery and the motor, or more precise, between the battery and the rest of electronics. There is no point of measuring charging capacity, as it will depend on the battery condition. The battery usually attached to the electronics with some kind of connector. Get a pair of same male/female contacts and solder them to watt meter leads. Then unplug battery and connect it back via watt meter.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  Thanks, you have been very helpful.

Comment: I am told by the manufacturer that I can't wire the meter inline between the controller and the motor because the motor is 3 phase, and it will not be accurate.  The motor is a brushless dc motor.  I think this means that I will have to put the meter between the battery and the controller.  I understand that having the battery condition as another variable, it could obscure what I am tying to measure.  In this scenario, would it be better to measure amps than watts?

Comment: sorry, I miss read your earlier answer.  Time to get the unit apart.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is good.

I think you should compare Energy consumption instead of current consumption.

You will need 2 recording digital multimeters.

---

In order to estimate the energy consumption you need to measure and log the battery voltage as well.

Plot in Excel the function V(n) * I(n) and sum it over n.

You will get the total energy consumed over the observation time.

---

There are plenty of recording DMM digital multimeters.

Use a recording time step of 0.1 seconds or greater.